# Please Explain what this code's logic is and the kinetic js part

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, kineticjs

Can someone explain the functions `this.iterateItems` and `this.get` in the following code?

I came across this code via a friend and i need some help with the explanation part of this.

```
    var LimitedArray = function (upperLimit) {
    var storage = [];

    // default limit on length if none/invalid supplied;
    upperLimit = +upperLimit > 0 ? upperLimit : 100;

    this.push = function (item) {
        storage.push(item);
        if (storage.length > upperLimit) {
            storage.shift();
        }
        return storage.length;
    };

    this.get = function (i) {
        return storage[i];
    };

    this.iterateItems = function (iterator) {
        var i, l = storage.length;
        if (typeof iterator !== 'function') { return; }
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            iterator(storage[i]);
        }
    };
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var tail = new LimitedArray(50);

    var i = 0, j = 0;
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
        listening: true
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
        listening: true
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var player = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: 20,
        y: 20,
        radius: 6,
        fill: 'cyan',
        stroke: 'black',
        draggable: true
    });

    layer.add(player);


    // move the circle with the mouse
    stage.getContent().addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
        layer.removeChildren();
        layer.add(player);
        player.setPosition(stage.getPointerPosition());
        var obj = {
            x: stage.getPointerPosition().x,
            y: stage.getPointerPosition().y
        };

        tail.push(obj);
        var arr = [];
        tail.iterateItems(function (p) {
            arr.push(p.x, p.y);
        });
        var line = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: arr,
        stroke: 'white',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        lineCap: 'round',
        lineJoin: 'round'
      });
        layer.add(line);
        layer.draw();
    });
    stage.add(layer);
});
```

Here's the html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Collision Detection</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style=" background:#000; margin:auto; float:left;"></div>
        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/kinetic-v5.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/main_kinetic.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you need anything more,do comment. 
Thanx for your help.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about the code? We will certainly not explain every single line to you. So please be a bit more specific.

Comment: "this.iterateItems" function and "this.get function".
I didnt understand both of these.

Answer (score 1):

The class `LimitedArray` is a container-class. It has an array as a private variable (`var storage`) which is not directly accessible by the outside world. It does, however, expose some public functions to modify and access this array.

The function `this.get(n)` is an accessor function which simply provides access-by-index to the elements of the array. It returns the n'th element of that array.

The function `this.iterateItems(iterator)` expects you to pass a function as an argument. It then calls that function once for each element in the `storage` array passing that element to the function. It is a reinvention of the [array.foreach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function from the standard which the author obviously didn't know about. This is also not what you usually call the [iterator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator).

When you would, for example, want to output each of the elements in the `tail` LimitedArray in the console using the `console.log(object)` function, you would call `tail.iterateItems(console.log)`. In this program, however, the programmer of the code passes an anonymous function to it. This anonymous function passes each argument to another array. So it is just an elaborate way to copy all the elements of the internal `storage` array into the `arr` array.

Answer (score 0):

`LimitedArray` is a class which contains an `Array`.

And in the instance of this class, User is allowed:

- to push intems in that array
- to get item on some index
- and to do looping in that array

`get` is to access some item in that particular array.

`iterateItems` is to do a loop in that array. in `iterateItems` function, you need to pass, that particular array is passed by default.